# Post request not getting at server side

Tags: angular, mean

I am trying to use post method to send data to server side but I am not getting request at server side sent by the application. 
below is the code I am using angular 6, node.js & express.

login.service.ts

```
getUserDetails(username, password) {
    alert(username);
    var core_1, http_1;
    //post these details to API server return user info if correct

    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/login", {
      username,
      password
    },{responseType: 'text'})


  }
```

api.js
I am trying to fetch post request in below method but it didn't print anything on the console.

```
router.post('/api/login', function(req, res) {
    // do something w/ req.body or req.files 
    console.log(res.body);

    var username = req.body.params.name;
    console.log("username"+username);
    res.json({'status': 200, 'msg': 'success'})

});
```

Comment: do you link your `api.js` file and its methods into the app in the server.js file?

Comment: yes "get" method working properly issue is only with post method

Comment: are you Calling the `subscribe()` method

Comment: in your server.js, use: ```const api = require('./path/to/api`).router;
app.use('/api', api);``` then change all of your api routes from `/api/**` to `/**`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon i already define const api = require('./server/routes/api');

Comment: you havent linked it though have you? and you didnt add the `.router` to the end

Comment: did you add the `app.use('/api', api)` line?

Comment: yes, the code is present in my server.js

Comment: and did you remove the `/api` part of each `router.**()` within the api.js file?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon thanks after removing /api from api.js file it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the route path for post request remove /api it will work fine for me refer below code.

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    // do something w/ req.body or req.files 
    console.log(res.body);

    var username = req.body.params.name;
    console.log("username"+username);
    res.json({'status': 200, 'msg': 'success'})

});
```